# Why green control jumping up and down when debugging Swift in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Sometimes it is annoying when debugging in Xcode and green arrow goes further down, comes back and only after all I can evaluate a variable. Does it have any reason? Is it a bug in Xcode? Can I turn of this "feature"?

[image]

Comment: What? haha
Can you share a screenshot? What "green arrow" are you talking about?

Comment: so first the green jump into the for loop, then goes back, then goes to `total`, and at that point I can evaluate i.e. `a4`

Comment: i see. thanks. I haven't encountered that yet.

Comment: When you step through code, control does not necessarily flow from one source statement to the next in an orderly fashion.  The compiler very likely has reordered operations (even moreso in Swift than Objective-C) so the source line identification will jump around a bit as you step.  (You will see an extreme version of this with loops, where control will often jump back and forth several times between the beginning and the end of the loop, each time the loop condition is evaluated.)

Answer (score -2):

I have noticed the same thing while debugging Swift Code in xcode as well. I just think the tooling in xcode for Swift is not mature yet. It could just be that the debugger does not have a perfect mapping of the source code to the object code...